# Prove this maximal inequality

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, solution-verification, independence

For independent real random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$, and their associated sums $S_k:=\sum_{i=1}^{k} X_i$, show that

$$\max_{1\leq k\leq n} P\{|S_k|>4t\}\leq P\{\max_{1\leq k\leq n}|S_k|>4t\}\leq 4\cdot \max_{1\leq k\leq n} P\{|S_k|>t\}$$
for every $t>0$.

Here is what I did:

WLOG we can assume $n>1$, since the inequalities are clear otherwise. Let $A:=\{\max_{1\leq k\leq n}|S_k|>4t\}$. Since $\{|S_k|>4t\}\subset A$ for $1\leq k\leq n$ the first inequality is clear. Next define

$$A_j:=\{\max_{0\leq k\leq j-1}|S_k|\leq4t\} \cap\{|S_j|>4t\}$$

for $1\leq j \leq n$, with $S_0:=0$. Then we see that the $A_j$ are disjoints and $A=\cup_{j=1}^{n}A_j$. Since $A\subset \{|S_n|>2t\}\cup (A\cap \{|S_n|\leq2t\})$ we get

$$P(A)\leq P\{|S_n|>2t\}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}P(A_j\cap \{|S_n|\leq2t\})$$

$$\leq P\{|S_n|>2t\}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}P(A_j\cap \{|S_n-S_j|>2t\})$$

$$\leq P\{|S_n|>2t\}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}P(A_j)P \{|S_n-S_j|>2t\}$$

$$\leq P\{|S_n|>2t\}+\max_{1\leq j\leq n-1}P \{|S_n-S_j|>2t\}$$

$$\leq 2\cdot\max_{0\leq j\leq n-1}P \{|S_n-S_j|>2t\}$$

where the second inequality is because $|S_n-S_j|\geq|S_j|-|S_n|$ and the third inequality is because $A_j\in \sigma(X_1,\dots,X_j)$ is independent from $\{|S_n-S_j|>2t\}\in \sigma(X_{j+1},\dots,X_n)$. As before we have

$$\max_{0\leq j\leq n-1}P \{|S_n-S_j|>2t\} \leq P \{\max_{0\leq j\leq n-1} |S_n-S_j|>2t\}=:P(B)$$ Define

$$B_j:=\{\max_{j<k\leq n-1} |S_n-S_k| \leq 2t\} \cap \{|S_n-S_j|>2t\}$$

for $0\leq j \leq n-1$, with the understanding that the maximum is $0$ when $j=n-1$. Then again we see that the $B_j$ are disjoints and $B=\cup_{j=0}^{n-1}B_j$. Reasoning as before we get

$$P(B)\leq P\{|S_n|>t\}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}P(B_j\cap \{|S_n|\leq t\})$$

$$\leq P\{|S_n|>t\}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}P(B_j\cap \{|S_j|>t\})$$

$$\leq P\{|S_n|>t\}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}P(B_j)P \{|S_j|>t\}$$

$$\leq P\{|S_n|>t\}+\max_{1\leq j\leq n-1}P \{|S_j|>t\}$$

$$\leq 2\cdot\max_{1\leq j\leq n}P \{|S_j|>t\}$$

where the second inequality is because $|S_j|\geq |S_n-S_j|-|S_n|$ and the third inequality is because $B_j\in \sigma(X_{j+1},\dots,X_n) $ is independent from $\{|S_j|>t\}\in \sigma(X_1,\dots,X_j)$.

Putting everything together gives the second inequality.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The inequality is known as Etemadi's inequality (there are several versions, i.e. the constants may vary).

Comment: @saz Right. But is my proof ok?